# MySQL join 2 column which every column got string with command seperator and add same value

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

Hello guys,

I want to combine 2 column with same total comma separator and add same string in the middle, anybody can help me how to do it?

| column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c,d | 1,2,3,4 |  |

Output Table1

| column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c,d | 1,2,3,4 | a x 1,b x 2,c x 3,d x 4 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Virtually impossible in SQL; easy in PHP and many other languages.